# VB.NET Cell Value Changes Automatically

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a datagrid that lets user input information, and some of the cells are ReadOnly so that the values of those cells can be calculated when information is entered into the other cells. 
My problem is that I used CellValueChange handlers to update the calculations, but the ReadOnly cells are not displaying the right numbers until I click on them. I want to the ReadOnly cells to update as soon as values in the other cells are entered.
Thanks.

Comment: What datatype is the grid bound to? Does it implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: It is bounded to a dataTable, and i does not implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Answer (score 0):

In some projects I use [DataTable.ColumnChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.columnchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event instead of [DataGridView.CellValueChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to do some calculations on inserted value but I think we are in the same situation.

You need to force `DataRow` update after setting another cell value; using `DataTable.ColumnChanged` I can use this code:

```
    If e.Row.RowState = DataRowState.Detached Then
        Try
            YourDataGridView.CurrentRow.Selected = True
            YourDataGridView.CurrentRow.Selected = False
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    Else
        e.Row.EndEdit()
    End If
```